# MySQL Ajax Table Editor- Not showing file input

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm using this MysQL Table editor on this project: https://mysqlajaxtableeditor.com/. to add/update/delete mysql table

**stop_list**`(stop_list_id,full_names,nationality,gender,document_type,document_number,date_of_birth,hair_colour,height,eye_colour,remarks,status,photo_file_name,user)`.

The column which is giving me problems is **photo_file_name**. I have used the following code for add/edit mode for this column:

```
<?php
$tableColumns['photo_file_name'] = array(
    'display_text' => 'File Photo', 
    'perms' => 'EVCAXTQSFHO',
    'file_upload' => array(
        'upload_fun' => array(&$this,'handleUpload')
    ),
    'table_fun' => array(&$this,'formatImage'), 
    'view_fun' => array(&$this,'formatImage')
);
```

To my surprise I am getting text html input instead of file html input. Is this right or I have problems with my code. I am looking for file input whereby the user can choose/browse for the file.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

my code (generates file-input):

```
$tableColumns['my_img'] = array(
            'display_text' => 'image',
            'maxlen'   => 100,
            'perms' => 'EVCTAXQSHOF',
            'file_upload' => array(
                'upload_fun' => array(&$this, 'handleUpload'), 
                'delete_fun' => array(&$this, 'handleDeleteFile')), 
            'table_fun' => array(&$this, 'formatImage'), 
            'view_fun' => array(&$this, 'formatImage')
        );
```